# Two separate WAN uplinks for two different NAT networks

Tags: nat, route, static-routes, wide-area-network

I have a server running ubuntu 10.04 with four interfaces. `eth0` and `eth1` have static WAN ip's, and `eth2` and `eth3` are connected to two separate NAT networks `192.168.0.0/24` and `192.168.1.0/24` respectively. `eth0` is masqueraded and  NAT traffic from `eth2` is forwarded to it. In order to forward `eth3` traffic to `eth1` I have used these rules:

```
ip route add xxx.xxx.xxx.176/29 dev eth1 src xxx.xxx.xxx.180 table link2
ip route add default via xxx.xxx.xxx.178 dev eth1 table link2

ip route add xxx.xxx.xxx.176/29 dev eth1 src xxx.xxx.xxx.180

ip rule add from xxx.xxx.xxx.180/32 table link2
ip rule add iif eth3 lookup link2

ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth3 table link2
```

This setup is working fine. `eth1` is masqueraded and NAT traffic from `eth3` is forwarded to it. But I feel some rules above are redundant, and there must be a simpler way of achieving it. Are there any better ways of doing it?